# Exact match in elastic search

Tags: java, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search, exact-match

I have indexed large pdf files into elastic search engine. I have analyzed this Unstructured Data with a snowball analyzer. this converts words like "running" to "run" using the snowball filter.  but what if I want to search exactly for word "running"? this does not help me.

I cannot go for using another field as these are larger files and can increase the index size in a larger extent.

So how can I use the snowball filter to use something like "preserver_original". so that I can have original word preserved along with the stemmed word.

is there any way or alternative way to analyze the field as per my requirement??

Answer (score 1):

You can use "stemming in situ":
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stemming-in-situ.html